# Find an explicit decomposition into direct product of matrix algebras over division rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

Find an explicit decomposition into direct product of matrix algebras over division rings of $M_2(\mathbb{F}_2)\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_2}M_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$.

Actually I have completely no idea about this problem. Please help me with the solutions or even some hints! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: $$M_n(k)\otimes_k M_m(k)\cong M_{nm}(k)$$ via the Kronecker product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What if the given ring becomes M2(F4)⊗M2(F4)?